# appengine: how to use validator in Class:Property?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, validation

described in http://code.google.com/intl/en/appengine/docs/python/datastore/propertyclass.html#Property

but there is no example code.

i code sth like:

```
class Model(db.Model):
  email = db.EmailProperty(validator=clean_email)

  def clean_email(self,value):
    if ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Model(db.Model):

  def clean_email(value):
    if ...

  email = db.EmailProperty(validator=clean_email)
```

use a argument. and the argument itself is the value of email in this case.

Comment: This shouldn't work.  In general a raw function inside a class like clean_email here is not visible to any class methods, etc of the class.  I don't see why it would be visible to the property.  Am I missing something?

Comment: until the class has finished being defined (that is, get to the end of the class declaration), the scope will allow you to access Model.x as just x (since model is not defined yet). If that code was inside a function (and as such, ran at runtime, instead of as an argument to emailproperty, which is evaluated at class definition time), then you would be correct.

Answer (score 1):

You need to either define the method before the property, as joetsuihk demonstrates, or define it as a function, outside the class. I would recommend the latter, as there's no reason for the validator to be associated with the class.